# TFLearn, tf.contrib.learn or tf.estimator?

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn, tensorflow-estimator

I've been tooling around with Tensorflow and TFLearn for a few months. I've made some progress. However, I was expecting to be able to construct a functioning scikit-learn type Estimator as a `TFLearn.DNN`. I can `fit`, and I can `predict`, but I can't do cross-validation because `evaluate` is failing for me. TensorFlow is throwing:

> ValueError: Cannot use the given session to evaluate tensor: the tensor's graph is different from the session's graph.

when I call `evaluate`. I thought the whole point of the TFLearn API was to abstract things like session management away from my code.

I have asked questions about problems I've had with TFLearn in several forums, including on the project's GitHub page. Unfortunately, I'm not getting any answers.

A few days ago, suddenly I encountered the `tf.contrib.learn` namespace. I'm seeing a lot of overlap between those classes and TFLearn. Then, I also found the `tf.estimator` class.

Finally, I just figured out that `tensorflow.contrib` sub-packages are third-party contributions. This leads me to wonder whether the original TFLearn is simply being absorbed into the larger TensorFlow package. Which direction is the code flowing?

I don't care what I use, as long as I get all the functionality of a scikit-learn estimator object.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to use the official sub-modules of TensorFlow like `tf.data` and `tf.estimator`. They should be well maintained and features are added quickly.

For instance, @mrry seems in charge of `tf.data` and the module is very clean, easy to use and compatible with `tf.estimator`.

The module `tf.estimator` is a bit less clear, and comes from `tf.contrib.learn`. Don't take my word for it but I think `tf.estimator` will slowly replace `tf.contrib.learn` and it should be the official high-level API for TensorFlow (along with `tf.keras`).

---

You can find more information in the official [blog post](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-tensorflow-datasets.html), where they explain the relationship between all modules.

[image: Organization of TensorFlow modules]